# SQLite not functioning well c#

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;

namespace DataAccessLibrary
{
    public static class DataAccess
    {
        public static void InitializeDatabase()
        {
            using (SqliteConnection db =
                new SqliteConnection("Filename=Crab.db"))
            {
                db.Open();
                String tableCommand = "create table if not exists MyTable (Crab integer primary key AutoIncrement," + " Box varchar(20)," + " Data varchar(20)," + "Data1 varchar(20)," + " Data2 varchar(20)," + "Data3 varchar(20)," + " Data4 varchar(20)," + " Data5 varchar(20))";
                SqliteCommand createTable = new SqliteCommand(tableCommand, db);
                createTable.ExecuteReader();
            }
        }

        public static void AddData(string inputText,string inputText1,string inputText2)
        {
            using (SqliteConnection db =
                new SqliteConnection("Filename=Crab.db"))
            {
                db.Open();
                SqliteCommand insertCommand = new SqliteCommand();
                insertCommand.Connection = db;
                insertCommand.CommandText = "insert into MyTable (Data,Data1,Data2) values (@Data,@Data1,@Data2)";            
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", inputText);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data1", inputText1);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data2", inputText2);
                insertCommand.ExecuteReader();
                db.Close();
            }
        }

        public static void Add(string inputText3,string inputText4,string inputText5)
        {
            using (SqliteConnection db =
                new SqliteConnection("Filename=Crab.db"))
            {
                db.Open();
                SqliteCommand insertCommand = new SqliteCommand();
                insertCommand.Connection = db;
                insertCommand.CommandText = "insert into MyTable (Data3,Data4,Data5) values (@Data3,@Data4,@Data5)";
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data3", inputText3);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data4", inputText4);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data5", inputText5);
                insertCommand.ExecuteReader();
                db.Close();
            }
        }

        public static List<String> GetData()
        {
            List<String> entries = new List<string>();
            using (SqliteConnection db =
                new SqliteConnection("Filename=Crab.db"))
            {
                db.Open();
                SqliteCommand selectCommand = new SqliteCommand
                  ("select Crab from MyTable", db);
                selectCommand = new SqliteCommand
                   ("select Box from MyTable", db);
                selectCommand = new SqliteCommand
                   ("select Data from MyTable", db);
                selectCommand = new SqliteCommand              
                    ("select Data1 from MyTable", db);
                selectCommand = new SqliteCommand
                    ("select Data2 from MyTable", db);
                selectCommand = new SqliteCommand
                    ("select Data3 from MyTable", db);
                selectCommand = new SqliteCommand
                    ("select Data4 from MyTable", db);
                selectCommand = new SqliteCommand
                    ("select Data5 from MyTable", db);
                SqliteDataReader query = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (query.Read())
                {
                    entries.Add(query.GetString(0));
                }

                db.Close();
            }

            return entries;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: This is the data for my code, here's the provided sql data]

May i know why is the data inserted in this manner? i am trying to make it 6 records in a single row. Please help! Is there a way to make it fill up first row instead of new row?

```
<Page
    x:Class="UWPDataTest.BlankPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UWPDataTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="Data3" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1300"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Data4" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1300"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Data5" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1300"/>
            <Button x:Name="button" Content="Done" Click="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="694,190,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.684,0.293"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

</Page>
```

Here's the layout of the design. There's 2 pages altogether, with tb name Data - Data5.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. The code is doing exactly what it says - Add inserts only columns 3-5 and AddData inserts only columns 0-2 - each insert is a new row

Comment: Well, you're executing two separate `INSERT` statements. Each `INSERT` will create a new record in your table. Combine them into one statement.

Comment: @MartinZikmund  Hi, thanks for the prompt response!! May i ask how can i make it to update 3-5 instead? Sorry, i am a newb to c# and sqlite.

Comment: @Pierre-LoupPagniez ^! Thanks for prompt response! May i know what can i do?

Comment: Check UPDATE keyword in SQL, that does exactly this :-)

Comment: How do you need which row (Crab) to update when you click on the button?

Comment: @mm8 I did something like first design view to insert 0 - 2 data and made a toggle button which if else condition to fill in 3-5.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you execute a command it creates a new row, you are executing it 2 times in 2 seperate methods that is why you are creating 2 rows, so if you need all textboxes data in 1 row, you have to execute them together in just one method, like below.

```
public static void AddData(string inputText,string inputText1,string inputText2,string inputText3,string inputText4,string inputText5)
{
    using (SqliteConnection db =
        new SqliteConnection("Filename=Crab.db"))
    {
        db.Open();
        SqliteCommand insertCommand = new SqliteCommand();
        insertCommand.Connection = db;
        insertCommand.CommandText = "insert into MyTable (Data,Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4,Data5) values (@Data,@Data1,@Data2,@Data3,@Data4,@Data5)";            
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", inputText);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data1", inputText1);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data2", inputText2);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data3", inputText3);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data4", inputText4);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data5", inputText5);
        insertCommand.ExecuteReader();
        db.Close();
    }
}
```

you just need this **AddData** method, and you do can remove the **Add** method because it is just an extra method.

Comment: thank you for your prompt reply! This actually help! But i also added a button with if else condition to ensure both side entry to fill in the same row! THANK yall for the effort !